# Redux Toolkit -selectById

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

I tried to use selectbyId helper method of  reduxtoolkit without a success can anyone help me with this

1. Category Slice

   ```
   export const {
    selectAll:selectCatetories,selectById:selectCategoryById
    }=categoriesAdapter.getSelectors(state=>state.inventory.categories.categories)
   ```
2. Category Component

   ```
   const category=useSelector((id)=>selectCategoryById(id))
   ```

I am sure there is something wrong with my implementation

Answer (score 3):

To get your category with an Id, you will need to create a [custom selector with reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#q-how-do-i-create-a-selector-that-takes-an-argument)

```
import { createSelector } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const { selectById } = categoriesAdapter.getSelectors();

export const getCategoriesState = (rootState) => rootState.categories; // I am assuming you have a 'categories' reducer in your redux store.

export const selectCategoryEntity = (id) => {
   return createSelector(getCategoriesState, (state) => selectById(state, id));
}
```

Then, you will be able to use the selector hook in your React component:

```
const category = useSelector(selectCategoryEntity(id));
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to pass the state to the useSelector function.

```
const category = useSelector((state)=>selectCategoryById(state, id))
```